# Jackson unable to parse ISO8601

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson

We get a HttpResponse with a date as one json attribute, the date is formatted in ISO8601 (e.g. 2020-03-13T00:00:35.570+0000) but Jackson throws following Exception:

`java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2020-03-13T00:00:35.570+0000' could not be parsed at index 23`

I`ve written the following Test (spock) which fails reproduceable.
I need to know how to parse the date.
Thanks for your help!

```
class TestJackson extends Specification{

    def 'test date format'(){
        given:
        def jsonString = """{"myDate":"2020-03-13T00:00:35.570+0000"}"""

        and:
        def objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        when:
        def resp = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Response)

        then:
        resp.myDate != null
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class Response {
        ZonedDateTime myDate
    }
}
```

The Test uses following Dependencies:

- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.3
- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.3

Comment: Try changing `ZonedDateTime` to `OffsetDateTime`. The exception is from Java, not Jackson.

Comment: Thats it, thanks :D

Comment: I'll write up an answer with more detail then, glad it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jackson is not the issue here; you'd get the same exception if you called `ZonedDateTime.parse("2020-03-13T00:00:35.570+0000")`. According [to the API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), `ZonedDateTime` uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` to parse. `ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` is

> a date-time with offset and zone, such as
>   '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'

The value you were trying to parse has an offset but no zone so you need to convert it to [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), which uses `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` to parse.  `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`

> ...parses a date-time with an offset, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00'.